# Slider de noticias

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Quería hacer un `slider` infinito que contenga noticias, para ello quiero que cada imagen muestre un texto que a su vez sea un enlace a la noticia para poder leerla en profundidad.

Aquí mismo hay un ejemplo: [Pagina de noticias con slider parecido](http://www.rcdmallorca.es/ca)

La cosa es que se hacer un slider infinito de imágenes, pero no se como añadir el enlace.

Por ahora tengo esto.

**Mi HTML:**

```
        <div class="Banner_Noticias">
            <a href="clasificacion.html" id="Enlace1" target="_blank">Enlace noticia</a>
        </div>
```

**Mi CSS:**

```
.Banner_Noticias{
height: 433px;
width: 650px;

border: solid 15px;
border-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 20px;

margin-left: 40px;


background-size: 100% 100%;    /* Redimensionar imagen :) */

/* Animacion */
animation: Animacion_Banner_Noticias 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes Animacion_Banner_Noticias{
0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(../Img/Imagen1.jpg);
    opacity: 1;        
}

31%, 34%{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

35%, 65% {
    background-image: url(../Img/Imagen2.jpg);
    opacity: 1%;
}

66%, 69%{
    opacity: 0.7%;
}

70%, 100% {
    background-image: url(../Img/Imagen3.jpg);
    opacity: 1%;
}
}
```

El problema es que así, todas las imágenes contienen el mismo enlace y obviamente este debe cambiar según la imagen.

Pienso que quizás debe hacerse por el `CSS`, pero la verdad que nada da el resultado deseado. ¿Hay alguna propiedad `CSS` que permita introducir enlaces? Es decir, yo con `background-color` pongo la imagen, ¿hay algo para enlaces? ¿Si no, como se haría?

Gracias

Comment: Yo estoy haciendo una pagina de noticias, y no existen slider infinitos 'eso creo', la manera en la que yo lo hice fue poner en una base de datos las noticias y luego desde el carrusel(slider ya creado en bootstrap) llamo a cada noticia almacenada en la db

Comment: Con infiníto me refiero que nunca para, cuando llega a la última vuelve a empezar. Quizas me he expresado mal.

Comment: En el enlace de ejemplo se ve claramente lo que quiero, y es que cada imágen contenga un enlace a la noticia en cuestión.

Comment: Agrégale un botón, esa fue la solución para mi. Dependiendo del id de la noticia que cree un botón el cual te dirige a la noticia en cuestión.

Comment: Para hacer que el enlace te ocupe toda la imágen pon el enlace afuera del `div`, o ponselo como evento `on-click` del `div` en cuestión y con el estilo css `cursor: pointer` para mostrar el típico cursor mano del enlace, para meterle el enlace dinámico no se me ocurre otra que no sea con `javascript`. Puedes comparar el atributo `src` de la imagen y asignar el enlace según el nombre de la imágen o puedes assignar el enlace según el id que más te convenga.

Answer (score 1):

aqui un posible solucion de lo que buscas, es solo ponerle un boton que tiene un enlace a donde estara tu noticia, no se si tus noticias las tienes almacenada en base de datos, de ser asi tendras que pasarle un ID cuando presionas el boton para que muestre la noticia correspondiente.

```css
body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */
.navbar-wrapper > .container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}


/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}


/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img class="first-slide" src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339684178-3a239570f315?q=75&fm=jpg&s=c39d9a3bf66d6566b9608a9f1f3765af" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Muertes Masivas</h1>
              <p>En este dia han muerto 30 personas por mano criminal</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://es.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" role="button">Leer Mas</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" src="http://unsplash.s3.amazonaws.com/batch%209/barcelona-boardwalk.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>La pobreza asesina.</h1>
              <p>La pobreza en el mundo esta creciendo</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://google.com" target="_blank"  role="button">Leer Mas</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img class="third-slide" src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339134316-0e91dc9ded92?q=75&fm=jpg&s=883a422e10fc4149893984019f63c818" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>No al racismo</h1>
              <p>Personas hacen marcha pacifica en contra del racismo</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://youtube.com" target="_blank" role="button">Ver Mas</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
      </a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```